# Chromecast keeps on disappearing on openwrt-based network

Tags: openwrt, chromecast

I keep on getting into a frustrating situation where Chromecast is connected to the network, but my phone can't see it. Initially my phone will see chromecast, I'll start streaming and shortly thereafter Chromecast disappears. Rebooting Chromecast and my phone doesn't make a difference. I suspect my openwrt router is at fault. Are there any Chromecast-specific settings that I need to be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the links found at the bottom of this answer, I applied the following changes and the problem seems to be gone:

- Wireless -> Edit both the 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz interfaces -> Advanced Settings -> Uncheck "Disassociate On Low Acknowledgement"
- Network -> Interfaces -> LAN -> Edit -> Physical Settings -> Check "Enable IGMP snooping"
- System -> Software -> Update lists -> Install the "igmpproxy" package

Related reading:

- https://forum.openwrt.org/t/can-only-find-chromecast-in-android-apps-for-a-short-time-after-router-restart/41824/4
- https://support.google.com/chromecast/thread/355932?hl=en
- https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/wan/udp_multicast